# Two structures of the same type on the same space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Do we ever use two structures of the same type on the same underlying space? In other words, are there any areas of study that utilise spaces of the type $(X,a,b)$ where $X$ is a space and $a,b$ could be different choices of topologies, group operations, inner products, etc.?

One of the only examples I can think of is a ring which is a set equipped with two different monoid operations (with additional properties). Apart from this, which structures (e.g. topologies, metrics, norms, etc.) do we ever use more than one of for a given underlying space? Operations are one thing, but I'm particularly interested in if two topologies are ever used in tandem and what the applications would be.

Comment: The use of different topologies on spaces of functions is endemic in functional analysis. The Wikipedia article on [weak topologies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_topology) may be a useful starting point.

Comment: Another example of this would be Lie Groups which are both groups and manifolds at the same time. Typically, when one has two structures on an underlying set, they are required to satisfy some compatibility conditions (i.e. the structures are required to relate to one another up to some criterion).

Comment: Since you mention norms, there are many different norms on $\mathbb R^n$ in use for many different purposes: the ordinary "Pythagorean" norm (aka the $L^2$ norm); the "taxicab" norm (aka the $L^1$ norm); the "sup" norm (aka the $L^\infty$ norm). And then, on top of those three, the infinitely many different $L^p$ norms as $p \in [0,\infty]$ varies.

Comment: For a while people studied "bitopological spaces"; spaces with two topologies on them, but I've not seen many interesting results regarding them. But it could serve as a search term in MR to find more papers. A Google search finds [this](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/bitopological+space), e.g.